# How to make a square with any symbol, using ruby loops?

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to make a square using ruby loops. The square needs to be constructed using any symbol and any number inputted by the user. For example, if the input_number = 4 and the symbol_chosen = &, then all sides of the square should have 4*& on each side.

I have tried a simple method. I collected two user inputs, 1. input_number and 2. symbol_chosen. Then, I created a loop with nested value of symbol_chosen*input_number. I know that this code will not give me 4 sides of the square but I don't understand why I can't even get one side of the square with this code.

```
puts "Please insert a symbol (eg. #, @, $, %, ^, &, *, _, -, +, =)"
symbol = gets.chomp

puts "Please insert a number"
number = gets.chomp.to_i

loop do
    symbol*number
    break
end
```

I want to know any errors that I have in this code which are preventing it from working. Also, I want to know what I should add in this code to make it form a 4 sided square with any character and number(representing the length), using ruby loop.

Comment: Hint: Consider what a square is. Repeat *N* times for the top row, then one character, *N-2* spaces, one character, and the last row is the same as the first. The interior is repeated *N-2* times. In Ruby that translates to `(number-2).times do`

Comment: typing just `symbol*number` does nothing. Do you want to `puts` or `print` that to the screen?

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems in your code:

1. You are computing `symbol*number`, but you are not doing anything with the result. You are simply ignoring it. You are not storing it in a variable or returning it from the block or printing it or anything else.
2. You are immediately `breaking` from the `loop`, therefore, it will only ever be executed once.
3. You never print anything.

There are infinite ways of approaching this problem, here is one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def make_square(number = 3, symbol = '*')
    return '' if number.zero?

    symbol = symbol.dup.freeze

    return symbol if number == 1

    solid_line = (symbol * number)
    middle_line = (symbol + ' ' * (number - 2) + symbol)
    middle_lines = ([middle_line] * (number - 2))

    return [
      solid_line,
      *middle_lines,
      solid_line
    ].join("\n").freeze
end

def print_square(number = 3, symbol = '*')
    puts make_square(number, symbol)
end

def ask_input
    return ask_number, ask_symbol
end

def ask_number
    puts 'Please enter a number'
    read_number
end

def ask_symbol
    puts 'Please enter a symbol (eg. #, @, $, %, ^, &, *, _, -, +, =)'
    read_symbol
end

def read_number
    Integer(gets).tap do |number|
    raise ArgumentError, "`number` must be non-negative but is #{number}" if number.negative?
    end
end

def read_symbol
    gets.chomp.tap do |symbol|
    raise ArgumentError, "`symbol` must be a single character" if symbol.size > 1
    raise ArgumentError, "`symbol` must be printable and visible" unless /\p{Graph}/ =~ symbol
    end.freeze
end

def main
    number, symbol = ask_input

    puts 'This is the square:'
    puts
    print_square(number, symbol)
end

main

# $ print_square.rb
# Please enter a number
# 0
# Please enter a symbol (eg. #, @, $, %, ^, &, *, _, -, +, =)
# █
# This is the square:
# 
#####
# $ print_square.rb
# Please enter a number
# 1
# Please enter a symbol (eg. #, @, $, %, ^, &, *, _, -, +, =)
# █
# This is the square:
# █
#####
# $ print_square.rb
# Please enter a number
# 2
# Please enter a symbol (eg. #, @, $, %, ^, &, *, _, -, +, =)
# █
# This is the square:
# ██
# ██
#####
# $ print_square.rb
# Please enter a number
# 3
# Please enter a symbol (eg. #, @, $, %, ^, &, *, _, -, +, =)
# █
# This is the square:
# ███
# █ █
# ███
#####
# $ print_square.rb
# Please enter a number
# -1
# ./print_square.rb:41:in `block in read_number': `number` must be non-negative but is -1 (ArgumentError)
#   from ./test.rb:40:in `tap'
#   from ./test.rb:40:in `read_number'
#   from ./test.rb:31:in `ask_number'
#   from ./test.rb:26:in `ask_input'
#   from ./test.rb:53:in `main'
#   from ./test.rb:60:in `<main>'
#####
```

This may look like overkill, but by separating the different sub-problems and sub-sub-problems etc. out into different methods, we can easily test each sub-sub-problem in isolation and trace an error to a specific point in our code. For example, if we suspect that there is a bug in our number reading method, we can call just that one method and verifying its result instead of having to through the entire program of printing out the square. Conversely, if we suspect that there is a bug in how we construct our square, we can simply call the `make_square` method with different arguments without having to enter the symbol and number over and over again, e.g. like this:

```
8.times(&method(:print_square))
# 
# *
# **
# **
# ***
# * *
# ***
# ****
# *  *
# *  *
# ****
# *****
# *   *
# *   *
# *   *
# *****
# ******
# *    *
# *    *
# *    *
# *    *
# ******
# *******
# *     *
# *     *
# *     *
# *     *
# *     *
# *******
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Jorg W Mittag. This was so helpful.